# Echo jquery code with php

Tags: php, jquery

Hello guys i have the jquery code bellow and i want to echo this with php.

But it gives me error. any help please?

```
<?php

echo '
$( ".post_text" ).append("<div style='width:500px; height:15px; float:left;'>Wanna share this article?</div><div style='width:500px; height:150px; float:left; margin-top:10px;'><img src='http://img.youtube.com/vi/0Bmhjf0rKe8/mqdefault.jpg'></div>");';

?>
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @JaredFarrish Why would she?

Comment: @OzanKurt - Please be specific. I have no idea what you're talking about. The OP is also female.

Comment: @JaredFarrish She wanted to echo a code... She didn't want that it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the PHP string starting with single quote breaks (ends) at `style='` because the last character is a single quote and PHP thinks the string literal ends here, but it cannot deal with the rest of the string which now it thinks is PHP code. Ergo, you need to escape single quotes within a single quoted string (and double quotes within a double quoted string), e.g. `style=\'width: 500px;\'`.

Answer (score 0):

Dont forget to make the quotation mark carefully.

To display the code as plain text use the `htmlspecialchars` function.

```
<?php

echo htmlspecialchars('
$( ".post_text" ).append("<div style="width:500px; height:15px; float:left;">Wanna share this article?</div><div style="width:500px; height:150px; float:left; margin-top:10px;"><img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/0Bmhjf0rKe8/mqdefault.jpg"></div>");');

?>
```

Comment: That's going to break the Javascript.

Comment: He just wants to echo

Comment: You have double-quotes within a double-quoted string in the `$.append()` call.

Answer (score 0):

In this situation I would do it like the following, remove the inline css, switch out the single quotes for proper std HTML `"` quotes, and tidy up the readability of the HTML within the js by using `\`:

```
<style>
.share-article {
    width:500px; 
    height:15px; 
    float:left;
}
.share-article-img {
    width:500px; 
    height:15px; 
    float:left;
}
</style>

<?php
echo '
$( ".post_text" ).append(\' \
    <div class="share-article"> \
        Wanna share this article? \
    </div> \
    <div class="share-article-image"> \
        <img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/0Bmhjf0rKe8/mqdefault.jpg"> \
    </div>\');';
?>
```

hope it helps, each to there own ;p